# How can I get this += operator to work?

Tags: c++

I'm making my own string class and everything is working fine except one this: I'm trying to overload the `operator +=` operator so that I can do this:

```
string s1 = "Hello", s2 = " World";

s1 += s2;
```

So this is what I tried:

```
// In the string class,

string& operator +=(string const& other)
{
    using std::strcpy;

    unsigned length = size() + other.size() + 1; // this->size() member
    char *temp = new char[length];               // function and a "+ 1" for the
                                                 // null byte '\0'
    strcpy(temp, buffer);
    strcpy(temp, other.data());

    delete[] buffer;

    buffer = new char[length];
    strcpy(buffer, temp);     // copy temp into buffer

    return *this;
}
```

But in [my program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c794f6445e4427b5825fb90d2b677043-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51) I get no output after printing when using the code in main shown above. I also get no errors (not even a runtime error). Why is this and how can I fix this implementation?

Note: I know I can use `std::string` but I want to learn how to do this myself.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Did you use a debugger? If so, inspect the contents of `temp` after the first two `strcpy`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore `temp` is just `"World"` after the strcpy.

Comment: @MemyselfandI and that doesn't tell you anything? Is it what you expected? did you check out `strcpy`'s documentation?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I tried `strcpy(temp + len, other.data())` in place of the second one but it still won't work.

Comment: You'll want to look into using `strcat` instead of your second `strcpy` call.

Comment: @Paul `buffer` is a member of the class that holds the string, so I don't need `this->`.

Comment: @MemyselfandI for future reference, note how there were more problems in code that you hadn't provided. That's a good example of why you should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when looking for help, as Oli Charlesworth said. Just generating the example will lead you to solve the problem yourself a surprisingly high fraction of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem is here:

```
strcpy(temp, other.data());
```

You've already copied the first string into the buffer (in the previous line), but this then *overwrites* it with the other string's data. You want to instead *append* the other string's data to the buffer using [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/):

```
strcat(temp, other.data());
```

As Jerry points out, your other problem is that you're not correctly initialising your strings in the first place.

As an aside, if you're going to use `strcpy`, `strcat`, etc, you should really use the length-limited versions ([`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/), [`strncat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/)) to avoid potential buffer overrun issues.

Comment: @Paul Did you see the demo?

Comment: why use length-limited versions when the length was taken into account?  AAMOF why use any str* function over memcpy when all info is at hands?

Comment: @BalogPal: sure, the length is taken into account when `temp` is allocated. But, if at some point one of the strings has its terminating `\0` go missing, then this will still encounter a buffer overrun because `strcpy` will just happily keep copy right off the end of `temp`.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work now with your solution. Thanks. -- http://ideone.com/8GJBRp#view_edit_box

Comment: @mac: another point why memcpy is preferable. If 0 characters are supported for this string your implementation will kill some of the content either with raw or n versions. Please edit the post.

Comment: @BalogPal: You're implying this wouldn't work for strings with embedded `\0`s? Absolutely true. However, the OP hasn't shown any sign that they would want to do such a thing, in which case using the `strxxx` family is perfectly fine for their needs. If they *did* want to go down that road, they'd have to do more than just switch to `memcpy`: they'd also have to start tracking string lengths internally, etc. I can't see any evidence in the question that that is really necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Just took a quick glance at the [demo you posted](http://ideone.com/8GJBRp#view_edit_box) in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055965/how-can-i-get-this-operator-to-work#comment24661948_17056014) under [Mac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17056014/1270168). This is your problem:

```
string(char const *str) : buffer(new char[strlen(str)]), len(strlen(str))
{}

// ...

string s1 = "Hello";
```

You're allocating the buffer in the constructor, but never copying the data into it. What happens if you just do `std::cout << s1;`?

---

**Edit**: By the way, I noticed at least two other problems:

- You're not updating `len` in `operator +=`
- Your copy constructor is making two `string`s point to the same buffer. This is bad, it will blow up when one tries to use it after the other `delete[]`s it.

Comment: I confirm that it doesn't print the s1 and s2, as-is, when std::cout << s1 and std::cout << s2 are added to main before the +=

Comment: I put `strcpy(buffer, str)` inside the constructor and I changed the first false part of the mem-init-list to `new char[strlen(str) + 1]` but still nothing -- http://ideone.com/8GJBRp#view_edit_box

Comment: I found that adding strcpy(buffer,str); to line 14 (inside the empty {} for the string(str) constructor) fixes the print problem.

Comment: Looks like it's working to me, what's the output you're expecting?